# React redux store add to cart and redux-logger problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Redux-logger not showing any action when add to cart button is pressed.

store.js

```js
import { legacy_createStore as createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";

// whenever action gets fired or dispatched we can catch them
// and then display them

// middleware is function between our actions firing and our root reducer 

// catches the action console logs out and then moves { good for debugging }
import logger from "redux-logger";
import rootReducer from "./root-reducer";

const middlewares = [logger];

// making a store                        
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  // values in array are function provided by logger.
  applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
);

// applymiddleware(...middlewares) => it will all the values inside array as
// individual argument in applymiddleware function.

export default store;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`createStore`](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore) function takes up to three arguments: root reducer, initial state, and enhancers, in this order.

I believe you just need to pass an initial state value as the second argument, moving the middlewares to the third.

Examples:

```js
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  undefined,
  applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
);
```

```js
const initialState = localStorage.getItem("state")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("state"))
  : undefined;

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
);
```

However, it is highly advisable to update and use [Redux-Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) and [`configureStore`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore). `configureStore` takes a single options argument, so initial state would only be provide if it was necessary/required.

Basic example:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(logger),
});
```