# TypeError: middleware is not a function (it is undefined)

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

When I am integrating my React-Native app with Redux-Thunk I got this error:

> TypeError: middleware is not a function (it is undefined)

I already tried everything on another stack overflow case but still error.

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import app from './reducers/index';

export default function configureStore() {
  const store = createStore(app, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));
  return store;
}
```

[error image emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APYvH.png)

Comment: You could switch to Redux-Toolkit which includes the Thunk middlware by default. Can you [edit] to include the complete error message and any accompanying error stacktrace?

Comment: Check the [createStore](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore) documentation, the enhancers is the third argument. Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77509099/8690857

Comment: sorry im confusing with that question that you send to me, since this is my third time using redux and i just copy and paste the folder and file from my old projects usually it works but now its not

Comment: You are using effectively deprecated Redux code. It's behavior may've changed in whatever version of `redux` you are currently using. It's also why I suggested integrating Redux-Toolkit, it'll save you from needing to write a lot of boilerplate Redux code and it makes creating/configuring the store even easier.

Comment: ooowhh thanks ill try. to redux-toolkit.

Comment: Ah, another thing you can check is that all the project dependencies are correctly installed, e.g. running `npm install` first and then starting the app normally.

Comment: Yes, thanks sir. im using redux toolkit and now its works.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked out for you. Cheers.